# Default browser opens blank pages

Tags: firefox, browser, default-browser

After accidentally setting my default browser to Thunderbird, my Firefox (Developer Edition) opens just a new window now every time a click a link. How can I fix this?

Comment: Maybe this helps https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/reset-preferences-fix-problems

Answer (score 0):

Solved by setting Firefox Developer Edition as the default browser from the Firefox preferences. This seems to don't work from the Ubuntu 20.4 settings!